# How to keep session alive for long selenium scripts in Automation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a task with Selenium in which while automating long scripts my session got expired and the page automatically get jumped to login page , (Developer is maintaining page session for 60 minutes at server side) . Please guide me if there is any way to maintain the session for as long as my script keeps running .

I tried using using cookies but null is received in output , seems like it does not work for me .

```
enter code here
        driver.get(url);
        Set<Cookie> cookies =driver.manage().getCookies();
        System.out.println("Cookies" + driver.manage().getCookies().toString());
        for(Cookie ck : driver.manage().getCookies())                            
        { 
          System.out.println((ck.getName()+";"+ck.getValue()+";"+ck.getDomain()+";"+ck.getPath()+";"+ck.getExpiry()+";"+ck.isSecure()));                                                                                                    
        }
```

Comment: Can the session be maintained in the browser (outside of Selenium) for longer than 60 seconds? If No then you cannot do anything as this is something that is controlled by the server. If it is then you need to provide more context - like the output of the code you have shared in your question.

Comment: One important thing. Selenium uses by default new temporary browser profile for each run. This means when webdriver instance is destroyed all cookies from that session are gone. To avoid this behaviour use an existing browser profile.